# How to compare present date to the date which is one year old

Tags: java, date

I am working on a java application where i need to compare present date to the date which is before one year or old. the old date will be coming from input file and it could be any date which is before one year. Please help me out

```
  long millis=System.currentTimeMillis();  
  java.sql.Date date=new java.sql.Date(millis);  
  String d1 = ord.getOrderDate();
```

i am unable to proceed from here`enter code here`

Comment: what is `ord` as I don't see it defined here...

Comment: if you are aware that the date from DB is older then what are you trying to do exactly? the the difference between those??

Comment: What is the ord refers here. If it refers data from input file, then what is the format of the String.

Comment: There is a particular reason why you are using java.sql.Date rather than java.util.Date ?

Comment: 1) ord is the object of the class from where i am bringing the orderdate

Comment: You ask several questions: how to read from file, how to parse a string to render a date, how to determine elapsed time, how to compare date-time values, and perhaps how to extract date-time values from a database. All of these have been addressed hundreds of times over already in Stack Overflow. Please **search Stack Overflow thoroughly** before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date` class has `before`, `after` and `compareTo` methods. See the Javadoc API. That should give you all you need.
[java.util.Date API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after-java.util.Date-)